Spring Boot 2.7, @Scheduled, ignoring initialDelay OneTime Execution Process, without using cron
I'm using Spring Boot 2.7
I would like to execute a process 120 (or another value stablished in application.yml) seconds after the microservice has started.
This is my code:
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class OneTimeProcessRunner {

    private final AtomicBoolean processLaunched = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    @Async
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void onApplicationReady() {
        this.scheduleProcess();
    }

    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 120, fixedDelay = 120, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    public void scheduleProcess() {
        if (processLaunched.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            this.runSingleProcess();
        }
    }

    @Async
    public void runSingleProcess() {
        log.info("Running One time Single Process.");
    }
}

The process should be executed only once!
I would like to set a solution without using cron.
Is this not possible using @Scheduled?
How I can programatically do it?
